# Searching for records in pymongo using a datetime criteria

Tags: python, datetime, mongodb, pymongo

In pymongo, the command `mycoll.find_one()` returned the following:

```
{u'name': u'John',u'sex':u'male',u'id':u'xbc541d',u'signup_date': datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 18, 22, 49, 20, 22000)}
```

If i search for a record using signup_date,no record shows up. That is `mycoll.find({'signup_date':datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 18, 22, 49, 20, 22000)})` does not return any records.

What is the error in my syntax for finding records using the date ?

Please Help
Thanks

Comment: That syntax should work (returning a cursor). If you write a minimal Python script that fails (both adding the record and then retrieving it), we might be able to help you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a same search on my database and it worked. Try giving the following:

```
  mycoll.find({'signup_date':datetime(2010, 12, 18, 22, 49, 20, 22000)})
```

You can also try option of narrowing your search results with "$gt" and "$lt" queries.

http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/